# Update an array after Toggle change in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a ScooterReservationView class in SwiftUI:

```
...
@State var extensionIDs: [Int] = []

var body: some View {
    ...
    List(scooterExtensionVM.extensions, id: \.self) { scooterExtension in
            ScooterExtensionRow(_extension: scooterExtension, extensionIDs: self.$extensionIDs)
    }
...
```

The scooterExtensionVM.extensions array gets its value from an API request, the extensions are totally dynamic based on the backend API.
Then I have the ScooterExtensionRow struct:

```
struct ScooterExtensionRow: View {

@EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState
@Binding var extensionIDs: [Int]

var scooterExtension: ScooterExtension
@State var isOn: Bool = true

init(_extension: ScooterExtension, extensionIDs: Binding<[Int]>) {
    self.scooterExtension = _extension
    self._extensionIDs = extensionIDs
}

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Toggle(isOn: self.$isOn) {
            Text(scooterExtension.name)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

}

My goal is to update extensionIDs array when the Toggle inside any of the ScooterExtensionRow view has changed. If any of the Toggle is switch on, I need to add the ScooterExtension's extension ID to that array, if its off, I need to remove the id from the array. This needs me for an API request later. (I need to collect all of the IDs of the enabled/toggled extensions)

The problem is: I cannot see in the docs any kind of callback action for the Toggle, where I can append/remove the value to/from the array, but maybe a callback is not the best way to do it in that Great SwiftUI World.

Can anyone help what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Is `extensionIDs` something that could fold into `AppState` in order to store (and publish) updates there?

Comment: I could put the extensionIDs into AppState, but I think its not solve my original problem, because I cannot append/delete elements to/from that array affter toggle switch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `ScooterExtension` has a property `id`, it can be done as follows:

```swift
Toggle(isOn: Binding<Bool>(get:{ self.isOn }, 
                set: { 
                    self.isOn = $0
                    if $0 { 
                       self.extensionIDs.append(self.scooterExtension.id) 
                    } else {
                       self.extensionIDs = self.extensionIDs.filter { $0 != self.scooterExtension.id }
                    }
                })) {
    Text(scooterExtension.name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see what you are saying in your comment. How about a new container type for the ids. Something like

```
class ExtensionID: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    let id: Int
    var isOn: Bool = true

    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
    }
}
```

Then you can bind the Toggle to the `isOn` property and conditionally display the ScooterExtensionRow (or whatever other changes you need based on a given id being off instead of actually missing from the array) based on this as well.

Does this make any sense?